# Route not working if not basic url polymer

Tags: routes, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, app-route

i am using [this](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/apps/routing) tutorial to use routes in polymer 2, i am setting route, and it's working fine when i run the standard url... 
For example: testurl.com (this works)
After that, every single page i go add path to route with no problem.
Example: testurl.com/product/123

My problem is now, if i refresh this page (testurl.com/product/123) not works more, my site loads, loads, loads, and not run...

I tried to configure my app-route like this

```
<app-location
  route="{{route}}">
</app-location>

<app-route
  route="{{route}}"
  pattern="/:page"
  data="{{routeData}}"
  tail="{{subroute}}">
</app-route>

<app-route
  route="{{subroute}}"
  pattern="/:idProduct"
  data="{{subrouteData}}">
</app-route>
```

This is how i am setting route

```
this.set('route.path', '/product/' + id);
```

Now i don't know how make a constructed url works normally, i don't know what i'm making wrong... Using iron-pages too, and not having problem setting change of pages too, only in routes with content after basic url.

Comment: Try to use ` <base href="/">`  or  ` <base href="./">` at index.html under head tag.

Comment: Is your server set up to return `index.html` for all requests regardless of the path?

Comment: as said @abraham, you need to have all paths routed to the index.html. Which you can do with .htaccess file

Comment: thanks guys, with this changes it worked! :)